# QuillJS - Format with out toolbar not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, quill

I am working on ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application. We are looking into few text editors where we can show Rich Text. I did google and came across Quill rich text editor.  **Its been only 60 minutes I started to read about QuillJS**.

I have a text in MS word document which is bolder and underline. I have code like below. When I copy text from my WORD document and paste into my Quill editor it is pasting like plane text. I cannot see bolder and underline

Below is my simplified _Layout.cshtml which I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/normalize/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/jsgrid/jsgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jsgrid-theme.css" />

    @*Application Styles*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/application.css" />

    @*Application JS Files*@
    <script src="~/js/image.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jsgrid/jsgrid.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <!-- Quill -->
    <!-- Main Quill library -->
    <script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>

    <!-- Theme included stylesheets -->
    <link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content appcontainer">
        @RenderBody()            
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is my complete my Index.cshtml

```
<div id="quillEditor" style="height: 600px; width: 100%;">  
</div>
```

In my javascript file.

```
 var options = {
        modules: {
            toolbar: false // no need of toolbar
        },
        theme: 'snow',
        readOnly: false,
        formats: ['bold', 'italic', 'link', 'strike', 'script', 'underline']
    };

    var quill = new Quill('#quillEditor', options);
```

But when I paste below code in https://quilljs.com/playground/ it works fine

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: false
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  formats: ['bold', 'italic', 'link', 'strike', 'script', 'underline'],
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

Comment: I tried your above code, but it works fine for me. Do you get some errors when pressing F12?  It would be nice if you provide a way to reproduce.

Comment: Did you try in ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application ?

Comment: I do not get any errors.

Comment: @itminus.. can you paste your code. Something I might be missing.

Comment: I just copy your code without any changes. I think it would help a lot if you show us the complete code of `Layout.cshtml` and your cshtml page. Also, do you encounter any error in the console when pressing F12?

Comment: I do not get any error messages when I hit F12 in google chrome. We solved our issue. Our main reason to use Quill is we want to show rich text format on UI. For this we use RtfPipe Nuget Package and converted rtf string into HTML and injected into  pre tag.